# Why do my shaders appear so dark in my linked collection?

Tags: instances, append

[image]
[image]
The first render is from the actual blend file. The other renders are when I use that first blend file appended/linked as a collection instance in another blend file. Why do my plastic containers look so dark, and my white ink looks black? I would share the blend file but it's a couple GB.